# Skin Tone Emoji Picker Custom Menu in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm creating a custom Emoji Picker in SwiftUI and want to add support for multiple skin tones.

This is my current progress, I have the emojis inside a LazyVGrid. I'll just paste for the moment the grid code:

[image]

```
private struct EmojiGridView: View {
    var cat: PSOEmojiCategory
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .title2) var minimumSize = 33
    @Binding var selectedEmoji: String
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // Category Header title
            Text(cat.name)
                .font(.title2)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .padding(.bottom, 4)
                .padding(.top, 20)
            // Emoji grid containing the emojis for each category
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: minimumSize))], spacing: 12, content: {
                // Iterate each emoji
                ForEach(cat.emojis) { emoji in
                    Button(emoji.emoji) {
                        self.selectedEmoji = emoji.emoji
                        dismiss()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    .font(.title)
                    .gesture(
                        LongPressGesture()
                            .onEnded({ _ in
                                
                            })
                    )
                    .highPriorityGesture(
                        TapGesture()
                            .onEnded({ _ in
                                
                            })
                    )
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

To support skin tones I need to add a custom menu like this one (iPhone keyboard)
[image: Skin Tone Picker]

I thought about adding an overlay to an emoji view, but I was wondering if there is a better way. Thank you.

Comment: Try popover especially if supporting iOS 17+

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum for the suggestion, but on iPhone the popover covers the whole screen, is there a way to override that behavior?